# How to use CasperJS to fill in AngularJS input fields w/out a form tag

Tags: angularjs, casperjs

I'm trying to write a CasperJS script which does a login at https://frontier.com/login.

I'm having trouble because:

1. it uses AngularJS so it seems I can't access and change the values held in its scope (eg. `ng-model='login.loginId'`). Setting the values directly on the elements doesn't have any effect.
2. the input fields are not wrapped with a form element so using the usual `fillSelectors()` with CasperJS isn't possible
3. `casper.exists('input#fid-login-inline-username')` returns true, but, `casper.sendKeys('input#fid-login-inline-username', 'blah')` gives an error saying `[error] [remote] mouseEvent(): Couldn't find any element matching 'input#fid-login-inline-username' selector`

The fields to work with are:

1. `input#fid-login-inline-username`
2. `input#fid-login-inline-password`
3. `div.login-form-container button.btn-primary` - for `click()`

**So, how do I edit the two input fields from casper into the angular scope?**

Here is an example of what I've tried:

```
casper.start('https://frontier.com/login', function() {
  this.echo('waiting for password input field');
  this.waitForSelector("input#fid-login-inline-password");
});

casper.then(function() {
  if (this.exists('input#fid-login-inline-username')) {
    this.echo('username input exists');
  }
  if (this.exists('input#fid-login-inline-password')) {
    this.echo('password input exists');
  }
  this.echo('filling in username and password');
  // these fields are not in a form element, so, use sendKeys to enter text...
  // the above echoes print the fields exist, and then these sendKeys 
  // operations emit an error that the fields don't exist.
  this.sendKeys('input#fid-login-inline-username', 'some@email.com');
  this.sendKeys('input#fid-login-inline-password', 'some-password');
});

casper.then(function() {
  this.echo('clicking login button');
  this.click('div.login-form-container button.btn-primary');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The app is creating two input elements per ID. If I get the second one then I can set the value and trigger an event for AngularJS to see it.

```
function login(un, pw) {
  $($('[ng-model="login.loginId"]')[1]).val(un).trigger('input');
  $($('[ng-model="login.password"]')[1]).val(pw).trigger('input');
};
this.evaluate(login, username, password);
```